# Проблема с выявлением файлов в данной директории в windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.x

Возникла проблема с выявлением файлов в данной директории именно с ОС win 10 после последнего обновления(до этого и на вин 10 работал скрипт), а на остальных версиях windows все работает.
Код:

```
import dbg
import app
import os
def RunCheckUp():
    Whitelist = ['test.dll','C.exe','folder','blabla.exe','xd.exe','plugins']
    path = os.getcwd()
    arr = []
    t = os.walk(path)
    for k in next (t):
        arr.append("/" + path + "/" + str(k))
    if k != Whitelist:
        ####Starting_Phase01#####
        for item in k:
            if not item in Whitelist:
                dbg.LogBox(" Удаление не нужного файла: " + str(item))
                try:
                    os.remove(item)
                except:
                    dbg.LogBox(" Прога сейчас закроется! ")
                    dbg.LogBox(" Удалите лишний файл: " + str(item))
                    app.Abort()
            else:
                pass
RunCheckUp()
```

Ошибка на win 10:
[image: Ошибка на win 10]

p.s Пробовал менять путь с помощью добавлением / но нет результата arr.append("/" + path + "/" + str(k))
p.s2 так же пробовал код проверки директории таков:

```
    path = os.getcwd()
    k = os.listdir(path)
```

В этом случае снова ошибка только на win10, а на других версия windows все работает. Ошибка вин10:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут принято вопросы писать на русском. Переводить вопрос на русский вместо автора не приветствуется, так как автор может не согласится с переводом своего текста - и возникнет конфликт. Для вопросов на английском языке можно зазать вопрос в английской версии сайта.

Comment: встроенный переводчик в браузере перевел сам, я не глянув нажал опубликовать, с переводом согласен.

Answer (score 0):

я попробовал ваш код. он полностью рабочий на даже на последней 10. есдинственное, мне не понятно это использемые библиотеки... это ваши модули?

```
import os
def RunCheckUp():
    Whitelist = ['test.dll','C.exe','folder','blabla.exe','xd.exe','plugins']
    path = os.getcwd()
    arr = []
    t = os.walk(path)
    for k in next (t):
        arr.append("/" + path + "/" + str(k))
    if k != Whitelist:
        ####Starting_Phase01#####
        for item in k:
            if not item in Whitelist:
                print " Удаление не нужного файла: " + str(item)
                try:
                    os.remove(item)
                except:
                    print " Прога сейчас закроется! "
                    print " Удалите лишний файл: " + str(item)
            else:
                pass
RunCheckUp()
```

если я Вас правильно понял, то вот этим кодом можно удалить файлы и папки, не входящие в белый список и только в том каталоге, где сам скрипт находится

Comment: Эти библиотеки используются в клиенте игры по стандарту(для работы с .ехе). Только я не пойму почему на некоторых win 10 выдаются данные ошибки.. Не на всех windows 10, а именно после какого-то обновления(может быть предпоследнего). Да, вы верно поняли, это скрипт для проверки файлов, если нет файла в Whitelist, но он есть в папке игры, то файл этот удаляется.

Comment: "я попробовал ваш код. он полностью рабочий на даже на последней 10. " - может проблема с os.getcwd win10 не правильно считывает путь.. должен так: D:\Test\*.* а он считывает так: D:\\Test/*.* (как видно из последнего скриншота)

Comment: почти... на втором и на третем питоне os.getcwd даёт путь через / слешь, что позволяет не экранировать его и указывать дополнительные адреса для, к примеру some_path + '/some_othe_folder'... по краейней мере у меня на винде и на линухе... возможно, я только предпологая, но не утверждаю, это может зависить от региональных настроект. попробуйте использовать / этот слеш

Comment: все таки не смог разобраться, у меня так и стоял слеш / в коде.. Через с++ реализовал

Comment: хорошо, давайте сделаем это вместе. расскажите, пожалуйста, что делаеют эти библиотеки dbg и app